# how to show loading image when tab content is loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tabcontainer with three panel, inside that I have gridview. When I user click on the tab the gridview is loaded. I want untill the gridview is loading, an img gif should be shown, and should got hide after the grid loads completely.
For that I had written code as:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="example.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="example" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {



        $("#mytab").mytab({
                ajaxOptions: {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: postData,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#loader').show();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $("#loader").hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        });

</script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <iframe id="iFrame2" runat="server" height="2px" width="2px"></iframe>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>


    </div>
  <asp:Panel ID="loader" runat="server" Wrap="true" CssClass="body"  >
                    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="width:322px; height:245px; border:1">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:322px; height:245px; border:1">
                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="322px" Height="245px" BorderWidth="0" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/loading.gif" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>

       <cc1:TabContainer ID="mytab" runat="server"  Width="100%"
                                Visible="true" AutoPostBack="true" >
                                <cc1:TabPanel runat="server"   HeaderText="application" ID="TabPanel1" 
                                    >
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                                        <table class="outline-tabs">
                                            <tr class="pagination-row">

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="tblGrid" AllowSorting="True">

                                                    </asp:GridView>
                                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </table>
                                    </asp:Panel>

                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </cc1:TabPanel>



            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run the application I get a error as:

`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected`

What is wrong with the above code, any file is missing, since I'm using jquery.

Comment: Where is your jquery? not implemented? Try two more methods: success: function() { console.log('data received') } and error: function(err) { console.log('Error: ' + err) }

Comment: like this                                                      success: function() { console.log('data received') }              error: function(err) { console.log('Error: ' + err) }                           is there any thing missing in my code as you said jquery?not implemented ? what will success and error function will do???

Comment: it seems, that this is your master-template and i dont see <script src="/path/to/jquery-VERSION.js">. On the other hand the jquery-selectors are only accessible when jquery-script is loaded and called. For the success and error-method in $.ajax please read the docs on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your  ...

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#mytab").mytab({
                ajaxOptions: {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: postData,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#loader').show();
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                      console.dir(data)
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                      console.dir('ERROR: ' + error)
                    }
                    complete: function() {
                        $("#loader").hide();
                    }
                }
            });
})
    </script>
```

with the console.dir(); you trace your incoming data-object in chrome or firebug. ie isnt a good browser for development.

hope this helps.

Comment: but still when i click on tab nothing is visible (no image loader)i had place a breakpiont but is not hitting .

Comment: ok. this is the time i have to ask if you are familiar with jquery or if your are a backendprogrammer. Your call is $('#mytab') which is selector so jquery knows all following methods are for this element in your DOM, than you try to invoke .mytab(). I dont know this method and thought that this is a method from a jquery-plugin. what says the console?

Comment: i know javascript,i dont know jquery,i just want when a user click on any tabpanel ,img loading should be visible while the content in the tabpanel(in my case gridview) is loading.mytab is the tabcontainer id.

Comment: i have 3 tabcontainer in my case,

Comment: even i dont know what is $('#mytab').mytab() i just got this code from this url http://jsfiddle.net/CQYSa/

Comment: i chnage my code now as this but still no result $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#tabMyApps").click(function(event) {
             $.ajax({

                 beforeSend: function() {
                 $('#PleaseWaitMessagePanel').show();
                 },
                 complete: function() {
                 $("#PleaseWaitMessagePanel").hide();
                 }

             });
         });
     });

Comment: hmm. Tomorrow I will work again with VS. So I try to build an example for you. Hope this isnt to late.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see. The examplecode uses `tabs` instead of `mytab`. This means that the example code uses jquery-ui (you find it here: http://jqueryui.com/).

For **tabs** you find the docs here (http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ klick on the link "view source").

So have a look in *your* compiled source with firebug or webinspector and look for jquery, jquery-ui and all source-files like images and css for jquery-ui.
If not implemented -> get the source.

After this you should be able to run your code.

For more help please post your *compiled(!)* source code.